# UNIX: How to change all hidden files to visible in a multiple sub directories

Tags: linux, files, rename, dot-files

I have hundreds of sub directories in a directory that all have hidden files in them that I need to remove the period at the beginning of them to make them visible. I found a command to go into each directory and change them to make them visible but I need to know how to make this command work from one directory up.

```
rename 's/\.//;' .*
```

Comment: Try it like this `rename -n 's/\.//;' ../*` the `-n` will see what happens without making any changes, then when your ok with it remove the `-n` option

Comment: I tried this command and its looking at the files above the directory I'm in not below? copied and pasted directly into putty

Comment: What does `from one directory up` mean?

Comment: If it's just a matter of visibility: `alias ls='ls -a'` and `shopt -s dotglob` (in `bash`).

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `find`:

```
find /some/path -type f -name '.*' -execdir sh -c 'mv -i "$0" "./${0#./.}"' {} \;
```

With Perl `rename`:

```
find /some/path -type f -name '.*' -exec prename -i -n 's!.*/\K\.!!' {} +
```

(remove `-n` when you're happy with the results).

Answer (score 2):

this is the line that fixed it all finally found the answer

```
find -mindepth 1 -depth -exec rename -n 's{/\.([^\/]*$)}{/$1}' {} +
```

Comment: This applies `rename` to files and directories alike, regardless of whether they actually need to be renamed or not.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `find` together with a simple shell script for doing the renaming and checking that no existing file is overwritten:

```
find . -type f -name '.*' \
    -execdir sh -c '[ ! -e "${1#.}" ] && mv "$1" "${1#.}"' sh {} ';'
```

The `-execdir` option will execute its argument inside the parent directory of the found name, and `{}` will be the base name (name without path) of the found name. This option is a widely implemented extension to standard `find`.

The `sh -c` script will simply make sure that the desired name is not already taken, and then it will rename the file.

The `${1#.}` parameter substitution will take the value of `$1` (the first command line argument of the `sh -c` script, which is a filename) and remove the initial dot.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
find . -iname ".*" -exec realpath {} \; | rename -n 's/\.(.*)/$1/'
```

File structure:

```
.
├── game
│   ├── .keie
│   ├── .kjae
│   ├── .ndhe
│   └── shame
│       ├── .alwo
│       ├── .asdjd
│       └── .kajd
├── .jsdsd
├── .lewe
└── .skdsd
```

Test run:

```
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/.lewe, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/lewe)
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/.jsdsd, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/jsdsd)
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/shame/.asdjd, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/shame/asdjd)
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/shame/.kajd, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/shame/kajd)
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/shame/.alwo, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/shame/alwo)
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/.ndhe, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/ndhe)
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/.keie, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/keie)
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/.kjae, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/game/kjae)
rename(/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/.skdsd, /home/george/Documents/askubuntu/rename/down/skdsd)
```

Results:

```
.
├── game
│   ├── keie
│   ├── kjae
│   ├── ndhe
│   └── shame
│       ├── alwo
│       ├── asdjd
│       └── kajd
├── jsdsd
├── lewe
└── skdsd
```

Information:

`realpath {}`: get the real path to file of interest

`-n`: used to test run, remove when you're ready to rename the files.

Comment: same error as all the other answers which means you are all probably right but I'm doing something wrong

Comment: with -n the command looks like it will run perfectly here is output...find . -type f -iname ".*" -exec basename {} \; | rename -n 's/\.//;'
rename(.test3, test3)
rename(.test1, test1)
rename(.test2, test2)
rename(.test3, test3)
rename(.test1, test1)

Comment: remove the `-n` when your ready to rename

Comment: yes without the -n I get this error for all 9 test files find . -type f -iname ".*" -exec basename {} \; | rename 's/\.//;'
Can't rename .test3 test3: No such file or directory
Can't rename .test1 test1: No such file or directory
Can't rename .test2 test2: No such file or directory
Can't rename .test3 test3: No such file or directory
Can't rename .test1 test1: No such file or directory
Can't rename .test2 test2: No such file or directory

Comment: I am in TEST running this command on TEST/T1/.test1 TEST/T1/.test2 TEST/T1/.test3 etc....

Comment: Yes i get same error here let me fix that

Comment: that would be great thanks I'll wait your reply

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -type f -name .\* -exec rename -n 's/\.//;' {} +
```

Comment: same error as the above solution 

Can't rename ./T2/.test3 /T2/.test3: No such file or directory

almost looks like its trying to rename the Directory or something?

Comment: That's because `rename` gets to see files as `./path/foo`.

Answer (score -1):

rename doesn't have a recursive option.  If you want to rename the files in the current directory and all its subdirectories, put the following script in the parent directory and execute it.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `find . -name ".*"`
  do
    rename 's/\.//' $i
  done
```

Comment: Can't rename ./T2/.test3 /T2/.test3: No such file or directory

got this error over and over in the test directory I'm playing with testing things out. Have 3 test directories with 3 test hidden files in each and all 9 files returned this string.

Comment: I don't understand why that code sample shouldn't work, but just for reference: use `$()` instead of `back ticks`.